# Django password reset with email using REST APIs

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth, reset-password

I'm developing a website using DjangoRest and Flutter and I want to add password reset using email.

I know that django.contrib.auth has views that help with password reset (PasswordResetView, PasswordResetDoneView, etc). But as long as I see, they return HTML files as a response when you call them in Postman.

Is there any way to use the same easy-to-use views but instead of getting HTML files, get an HTTP response so it can be called by the Flutter app?

Comment: Why not create views in DRF? here are the API docs: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. How can I do that? You mean change the views in django.contrib.auth?

Answer (score 3):

This can be handled in basically Two Steps:

*1. One is to send anything like OTP or Reset Link view email*

*2. The second is to verify whether the OTP/link either is valid or not with a new password.*

This can be achieved via simple function-based API views:
I can demonstrate the simplest form using OTP for basic understanding, as u said you are using flutter at frontend and that will be easier to manage otp instead of link

**Step 1: Add a top Field into User Model.**
Let's say we have field otp in the user model. Later we use it for verification purposes.

```
class CustomerUser(models.Model):
    #...
    otp = models.CharField(
        max_length=6, null=True, blank=True)
    
    # Method to Put a Random OTP in the CustomerUser table.
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        number_list = [x for x in range(10)]  # Use of list comprehension
        code_items_for_otp = []

        for i in range(6):
            num = random.choice(number_list)
            code_items_for_otp.append(num)

        code_string = "".join(str(item)
                                        for item in code_items_for_otp)  # list comprehension again
        # A six digit random number from the list will be saved in top field
        self.otp = code_string
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Step:2: Function to send Email with OTP on User Request**

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def reset_request(request):
    data = request.data
    email = data['email']
    user = CustomUser.objects.get(email=email)
    if CustomUser.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
        # send email with otp
        send_mail(
        'Subject here',
        f'Here is the message with {user.otp}.',
        'from@example.com',
        [user.email],
        fail_silently=False,
        )
        message = {
            'detail': 'Success Message'}
        return Response(message, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
        message = {
            'detail': 'Some Error Message'}
        return Response(message, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**Last Step: Verify OTP And reset Password**

```
@api_view(['PUT'])
def reset_password(request):
    """reset_password with email, OTP and new password"""
    data = request.data
    user = CustomUser.objects.get(email=data['email'])
    if user.is_active:
        # Check if otp is valid
        if data['otp'] == user.opt:
            if new_password != '':
                # Change Password
                user.set_password(data['password'])
                user.save() # Here user otp will also be changed on save automatically 
                return Response('any response or you can add useful information with response as well. ')
            else:
                message = {
                    'detail': 'Password cant be empty'}
                return Response(message, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            message = {
                'detail': 'OTP did not matched'}
            return Response(message, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    else:
        message = {
            'detail': 'Something went wrong'}
        return Response(message, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

So you can replicate it with your custom approach as well and can refactor it easily.
I have used Simple [API views](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/#wrapping-api-views) in these examples you can check the detailed information in DRF DOCS [Requests and Response](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/#tutorial-2-requests-and-responses) Section as well

So You don't have to use HTML at all, just can work with Response, HttpResponse whatever you prefer.